# How many minutes long was each of Ferris's breaks?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> Working alone at their respective constant rates, Audrey can complete
>   a certain job in $4$ hours, while Ferris can do the same job in $3$
>   hours. Audrey and Ferris worked together on the job and completed it
>   in $2$ hours, but while Audrey worked this entire time, Ferris worked
>   for some of the time and took $3$ breaks of equal length. How many
>   minutes long was each of Ferris's breaks?

My solution:

- Audrey's rate of work = $1/4$ per hour
- Ferris's rate of work = $1/3$ per hour

So, together they can complete $7/12$ of the job per hour.

So, if no one takes rest they can complete the job in $1/(7/12)= 12/7$ hours

But as one of them did not work full time, they needed to work $2$ hours. hence, Audrey took rest $= 2 - 12/7$ hours $= 2/7$.

So, each of Audre's break $= 2/21$ hours.

Is my approach right? If not, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation would be correct if **both** A and F took breaks together. Then the total break time for each would indeed be $\frac{2}{7}$. However, A worked full time.

I think it may be easiest to let the number of hours that F actually worked be $h$. Then F completed $\frac{h}{3}$ of the job, while A, working for $2$ hours, completed $\frac{2}{4}$ of the job.
Thus
$$\frac{h}{3}+\frac{2}{4}=1.$$
It follows that $h=\frac{3}{2}$. Thus F's breaks were for a total of $\frac{1}{2}$ of an hour, $10$ minutes each.

*Remark*: We could argue without equations. It is clear that A, working for $2$ hours, did half the job, so F did the other half. Since F can do the job in $3$ hours, F's working time must have been an hour and a half.

Answer (score 0):

ِDear André Nicolas;

I had a problem with your conclusion in remark section. If F did the half of the job in 1.5 hours, then A dedicated 0.5 hour for the job. Therefore, how could we conclude that F spends 30 minutes on break?

Thanks